# Is there a log of package management activity like recent removals?

Tags: apt, package-management, synaptic, log

Is there a log that shows recent activity done by the package management, like apt-get, dpkg, synaptics?

For example, you removed a bunch of packages but realized that a not-tracked application (for example under development) was actually dependent on some of them. So you would like to view the log of the removals in synaptic or other interface. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the history of `apt-get` actions, see `/var/log/apt/term.log`. It will include the interactive input/output as well, e.g. configuration choices.

The `/var/log/dpkg.log` log includes only what has been installed/removed, but it does not include output like DKMS errors for example. However, because DPKG is the base of the very packaging system, it does not matter which front-end you used, while for the APT log, this does only includes entries done by any of the APT front-ends.

Answer (score 6):

It seems that it can be found in `/var/log/dpkg.log`! :) Should have guessed..

Answer (score 2):

The Ubuntu Software Centre also keeps a history around, for those that prefer a GUI.

[image]